# How to put a webcam recording and a desktop recording side by side with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to directly put 2 `ffmpeg` outut side by side in order to output a video that has both videos.

The recording ares

1. a `640x480` webcam recording with:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 webcam.mkv
   ```
2. a desktop recording video of  `1600x900` with

   ```
   ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 100 -s 1600x900 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -threads 3 desktop.mkv

                 ---------------
                 |             |
      |----------|   desktop   |
      |  webcam  |             |
      --------------------------
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg \
-f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
-f x11grab -framerate 100 -video_size 1600x900 -i :0.0 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:900:0:(oh-ih)/2[left];[left][1:v]hstack" \
output
```

- Use `-framerate` instead of `-r` and `-video_size` instead of `-s` for [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab).
- The [hstack filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) will use the frame rate of the first input, so you may add the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) after the pad filter if desired.
- `-framerate 100` seems high and may not be sustainable.